# Xamarin.Forms IOS Unified Build error SQLite

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

When attempting to build my IOS project I am getting the below error and I'm unsure of how to fix it:

```
Error   94  Failed to resolve "System.Int32 SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection::InsertAll(System.Collections.IEnumerable)" reference from "SQLite.Net, Version=2.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets
```

Xamarin 4.0.0.1689
Xamarin.Adnroid 6.0.0.34
Xamarin.IOS 9.2.1.51

SQLite.Net PCL V3.1.1
Xamarin.Forms 2.0.0.6484

Answer (score 0):

I have now resoled this. The issue was the PCL project missing references to the same Nuget Package